# How to populate XML node values in Grid view in Asp.net?

Tags: web-services, rest, amazon-web-services

I am using a thirdparty webservice. I got the response in XML format.
Now, i have to show the XML node values in grid view.
The following code i tried so far.

```
  using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        // Get the response stream
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        //Label2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();


        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(reader);

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("ms", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05");

        XmlNode image = xml.SelectSingleNode("//ms:URL", ns);
        XmlNode FormattedPrice = xml.SelectSingleNode("//ms:FormattedPrice", ns);
```

Now, i want to show the values of XMLnode value in grid view.
Please inform  me, if you need more information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of Get the HttpResponse in xmldocument. 
I used XNamespace and XDocument.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05";    // Linq
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Then Use Linq to Read all Vlaues. Example:

```
var Image = xd.Descendants(ns + "Items").Elements(ns + "Item").Select(img => img.Elements(ns + "MediumImage").Select(img1 => (string)img1.Element(ns + "URL")).FirstOrDefault() ?? "Null").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XMLDataSourcefor that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10898/Introduction-to-XMLDataSource-control-in-ASP-NET-2

Best regards.